# Remove search option from django widget FilteredSelectMultiple

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using FilteredSelectMultiple widget in my form but i want to remove the search option from the widget.

[image]

forms.py

`study=forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True,widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(_('Study'),False))`

After rendering it's code comes out as a html paragraph with id="id_study_filter" and class="selector-filter". I tried to remove it using it's id but the following code didn't work.

`document.getElementById("id_study_filter").style.display = 'none';`

I also tried to hide it after a timeout, still it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#id_study_filter').delay(3000).hide();});
```

Answer (score 0):

The second solution works for me, even without delay.

Is the widget in admin form? Have you tried running the script from the console?

Comment: Yes the widget is in admin form.

Comment: Passing a .js file in `class Media` makes it work for me.

Comment: I am adding the script in html file, it should work too right?

Comment: As long as jQuery is loaded before script is being executed it should. Did you make sure your jQuery works by running something else?

Comment: Maybe the document is ready before the element is loaded so the script cannot select the element by that ID since it doesn't exist yet. You can maybe wait for the element to exist or use DOMContentLoaded.